# How to optimize portfolios in the PortfolioAnalytics environment with an individual objective function?

Tags: r, optimization

I want to optimize a data set of 7 assets and 209 returns numerically within the `PortfolioAnalytics` package in R. I want to set up an individual objective function, which is as follows:

```
f(u)= max! (rp-rb)-ETL(p,95%)
```

where `rp` denotes portfolio return, `rb` denotes a benchmark return (209x1 matrix) and `ETL`(p,95%) denotes the Expected Tail loss on a 95% confidence level.

The error for the code below is the following:

> ```
> objective name OF generated an error or warning: Error in checkData(weights, method = "xts") : 
>   The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'. 
> Error in apply(i, 1, fn, ...) : 
>   task 1 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
> Optimizer was unable to find a solution for target.
> ```

For the code on the very bottom, `R` is the matrix of returns (209x7) and `BM_r` are the benchmark returns (209x1 matrix).

I already tried using different solvers, but for this objective functions, the `DEoptim` algorithm must work. 
Moreover, it seems like the `ETL` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` requires a `timeSeries` object, whereas the `DEoptim` solver requires the `as.numeric` format.

The utilized packages are listed below:

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library("PortfolioAnalytics")
library("timeSeries")
library("fPortfolio")
library("ggplot2")
library("xts")
library("Quandl")
library("fImport")
library("fBasics")
library("zoo")
library("quadprog")
library("foreach")
library("iterators")
library("DEoptim")
library("pso")
library("GenSA") 
library("quantmod")
library("ROI")
library("fGarch")
library("Rglpk")
library("ROI.plugin.glpk")
library("ROI.plugin.quadprog")
library("ROI.plugin.symphony")
library("corpcor")
library("testthat")
library("nloptr")
library("MASS")
library("robustbase")
library("vars")
library("tsDyn")
library("cluster")
library("mvoutlier")
library("pastecs")
library("plyr")
library("itsmr")
```

And here is the code:

```
OF <- function(R, weights){
weights <- matrix(weights, ncol=1)
BM_r1<-BM_r
PFretu<-Return.portfolio(R=R,weights = weights)
Excess<-as.numeric(PFretu-BM_r1)
CV<-ETL(R,p=0.95,method = "gaussian", weights=weights)
Outp<-as.numeric(Excess-CV)
Outp
}

R <- Data 
fund <- colnames(R) 

PMFpf<-portfolio.spec(assets=fund)
PMFpf<-add.constraint  (portfolio=PMFpf,type="weight_sum",  
min_sum=0.99,max_sum=1.01)

PMFpf<-add.constraint(PMFpf, type="box",min=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
max=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.99,0.99,0.2,0.1,0.1))

sample_moments <- set.portfolio.moments(R, portfolio = PMFpf)

PMFpf <- add.objective(portfolio=PMFpf, type="return", name="OF")
.storage <<- new.env()
 opt.PMFpf<-optimize.portfolio(R, portfolio=PMFpf,  
 optimize_method="DEoptim",momentargs=sample_moments,  
 momentargs=sample_moments,trace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the parallell computing cores (from foreach) are still registered. 
The underlying c file for DEoptim cannot handle receiving commands in parallell. 
If you unregister these cores your code will run fine I guess.
Use e.g. a function like this before calling optimize.portfolio:

```
unregister <- function() {
  env <- foreach:::.foreachGlobals
  rm(list=ls(name=env), pos=env)
}
unregister()
```